# Logger not displaying logs in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, logging, winston

I have a nodejs app that's not logging to the console. what am I doing wrong?

```
import { createLogger, format, transports } from 'winston';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import DailyRotateFile from 'winston-daily-rotate-file';
import { config } from '../config';
import Sentry from  'winston-transport-sentry-node'

// Create a log directory to store logs

let logDir = path.join(__dirname, '../logs');

if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(logDir);
}
const logLevel = config.env === "development" ? "debug":"warn";

const dailyRotateFileTransport = new DailyRotateFile({
  level: logLevel,
  filename: `${logDir}/%DATE%-results.log`,
  datePattern: "YYYY-MM-DD",
  zippedArchive: true,
  handleExceptions: true,
  maxSize: "20m",
  maxFiles: "14d",
  format: format.combine(
    format.errors({ stack: true }),
    format.timestamp(),
    format.json()
  ),
});

const sentryTransport = new Sentry({
  level: "error",
  sentry: {
    dsn: config.sentry.dsn,
    environment: config.env,
  },
});

const logger = createLogger({
  transports: [ new transports.Console({
    level: logLevel,
    handleExceptions: true,
    format: format.combine(
      format.errors({ stack: true }),
      format.colorize(),
      format.simple()
    ),
  }),dailyRotateFileTransport, sentryTransport],
  exceptionHandlers: [dailyRotateFileTransport],
  exitOnError: false,
});
export default logger;
```

I have read the documentation and other posts but cannot find a solution, log files are created but there are no logs on my system's terminal